# UserNotification custom sound causing memory leak with app in background?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, unusernotificationcenter

I have an alarm app whose main functionality is playing a local notification with a 25-second custom sound at a specified time.  The user sets the alarm, the local notification request is scheduled and the app can sit in the background until the local notification is triggered.

However, 15-20 minutes after going into the background, when the [CPU usage is 0% and the memory usage is stable at about 17-20 MB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeHBW.jpg), the app terminates with the memory error "Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9".  There no spike prior to the app terminating.  applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning is *not* called in the AppDelegate before the app is killed.

I've reviewed a bunch of SO questions on the topic as well as the [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html) [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/responding_to_memory_warnings).  None of the advice seems relevant.  People seem to have issues with memory when they have high CPU usage or much higher memory usages.  And if the issue were cached images, why would it take 15-20 minutes of the app sitting in background for the memory leak to kill the app?

I've begun commenting out portions of my code and seeing how the app runs in background.  The issue seems to be coming from the custom 25-second sound.  So long as I set the notification to the default sound rather than my custom 25-second sound, I do not get this error.

How could memory usage in the UserNotificationCenter affect my app 15-20 minutes after going in the background?  How can I address this memory issue?

Comment: Have you used Instruments to see if there's actually a memory spike and what's causing it?

Comment: Also, do you get the same issue when testing on a device? You didn't say you're testing on the simulator, but be warned, if that's what you're doing, stop; the simulator is no place to test background behavior.

Comment: I use xcode's debug session instruments while testing on an iPhone 6, not a simulator.  I have watched the CPU and memory usage many times when the app is killed and have not seen a spike prior to the Signal 9 error. Do you know of an instrument I could use to get a better sense of what's happening?

Comment: Use the Allocations template in Instruments. This should leave you a record of what happened right up to the end (I hope).

Comment: Also I assume you're doing this according to the rules in the UNNotificationSound documentation.

Comment: One more thing; being terminated in the background is _normal_. How do you know that's not what's happening? You cannot expect your app to remain running in the background all the time.

Comment: I thought the Signal 9 error told me it's being terminated for a memory issue, not as part of the normal app life cycle.  I will use the Allocations instruments and get back to you.

Comment: The job of the system is to reclaim memory as needed. It does that by terminating suspended backgrounded apps. You should not expect to survive indefinitely once you are suspended.

Comment: Thanks @matt.  I do realize that I don't get to sit in background for forever, but I would like to understand if this is a true memory issue I can fix. 
Instruments did inform me that I'm getting a low memory warning ~1 minute before the app quits.  However, the memory usage stays consistent (~20MB) for the the 10-15 minutes before the memory warning.   https://imgur.com/a/JqXU5 .  So  if the memory usage is consistent, why do I only get the memory warning 10-15 minutes in? What's the best way to address this issue? Should I deallocate high-memory items before going into background?

Comment: What I’m saying is, why do you care? Your app is in the background. You should expect it to die.

Comment: Local and push notifications act differently depending on whether the app is terminated or not, so it does have a big impact on user experience and my app's functionality.  I also don't want to program around the expectation that I have a memory issue that causes my app to be killed.  I'd rather fix the problem.